# Resize 2 rectangles in a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I can not resize the two rectangles, but only the right one. What should I add to my code ?
I want also that when the lower edge of the left rectangle is moved, it also moves the upper edge of the right rectangle.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Resizing extends JPanel {

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100,100,150,150);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(300,100,150,150);

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 200));
    g2.fill(rect);
    g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 200));
    g2.fill(rect2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Resizing essai = new Resizing();
    Resizer1 rectangle = new Resizer1(essai);
    essai.addMouseListener(rectangle);
    essai.addMouseMotionListener(rectangle);
    f.add(essai);

    Resizing test2 = new Resizing();
    Resizer2 rectangle2 = new Resizer2(test2);
    test2.addMouseListener(rectangle2);
    test2.addMouseMotionListener(rectangle2);
    f.add(test2);

    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setLocation(100,100);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}

class Resizer1 extends MouseAdapter {

Resizing component;
boolean dragging = false;
// Give user some leeway for selections.
final int PROX_DIST = 3;

public Resizer1(Resizing r) {
    component = r;
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(component.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {
        // If cursor is set for resizing, allow dragging.
        dragging = true;
    }
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    dragging = false;
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if(dragging){
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        Rectangle r = component.rect;
        int type = component.getCursor().getType();
        int dy = p.y - r.y;
        switch(type) {
            case Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                int height = r.height - dy;
                r.setRect(r.x, r.y+dy, r.width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                height = dy;
                r.setRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, height);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("unexpected type: " + type);
        }
        component.repaint();
    }
}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    if(!isOverRect(p)) {
        if(component.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {
            // If cursor is not over rect reset it to the default.
            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        return;
    }
    // Locate cursor relative to center of rect.
    int outcode = getOutcode(p);
    Rectangle r = component.rect;
    switch(outcode) {
        case Rectangle.OUT_TOP:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - r.y) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_BOTTOM:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - (r.y+r.height)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        default:    // center
            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }
}

/**
 * Make a smaller Rectangle and use it to locate the
 * cursor relative to the Rectangle center.
 */
private int getOutcode(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.rect.clone();
    r.grow(-PROX_DIST, -PROX_DIST);
    return r.outcode(p.x, p.y);
}

/**
 * Make a larger Rectangle and check to see if the
 * cursor is over it.
 */
private boolean isOverRect(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.rect.clone();
    r.grow(PROX_DIST, PROX_DIST);
    return r.contains(p);
}
}

class Resizer2 extends MouseAdapter {

Resizing component;
boolean dragging = false;
// Give user some leeway for selections.
final int PROX_DIST = 3;

public Resizer2(Resizing r) {
    component = r;
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e2) {
    if(component.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {
        // If cursor is set for resizing, allow dragging.
        dragging = true;
    }
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e2) {
    dragging = false;
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e2) {
    if(dragging){
        Point p = e2.getPoint();
        Rectangle r = component.rect2;
        int type = component.getCursor().getType();
        int dy = p.y - r.y;
        switch(type) {
            case Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                int height = r.height - dy;
                r.setRect(r.x, r.y+dy, r.width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                height = dy;
                r.setRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, height);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("unexpected type: " + type);
        }
        component.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e2) {
    Point p = e2.getPoint();
    if(!isOverRect(p)) {
        if(component.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {
            // If cursor is not over rect reset it to the default.
            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        return;
    }
    // Locate cursor relative to center of rect.
    int outcode = getOutcode(p);
    Rectangle r = component.rect2;
    switch(outcode) {
        case Rectangle.OUT_TOP:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - r.y) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_BOTTOM:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - (r.y+r.height)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        default:    // center
            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }
}

/**
 * Make a smaller Rectangle and use it to locate the
 * cursor relative to the Rectangle center.
 */
private int getOutcode(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.rect2.clone();
    r.grow(-PROX_DIST, -PROX_DIST);
    return r.outcode(p.x, p.y);
}

/**
 * Make a larger Rectangle and check to see if the
 * cursor is over it.
 */
private boolean isOverRect(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.rect2.clone();
    r.grow(PROX_DIST, PROX_DIST);
    return r.contains(p);
}
}
```

Comment: You really should learn what an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and learn to correctly post one. A long wall of code and two lines of description will most likely get you no answers.

Answer (score 2):

Problems I see on inspection of your code:

- You are adding 2 JPanels to your JFrame, but only one will show since they're being added in a default fashion to a BorderLayout-using container. **Edit:** I see now why you're doing this, but as explained below, you should not be doing this. Only create one Resizing object and add it once to the JFrame. The one Resizing will show both rectangles, and the single MouseAdapter should be coded to allow you to interact with both rectangles.
- You are not making your Rectangle fields private and are allowing outside classes (namely Resizer1) to directly access and minipulate your fields. You'd be better off using public methods that allow other classes to selectively query your class for its state or to change your class's state.
- Don't use two Resizer classes, Resizer1 and Resizer2, and it is this as well as your adding two Resizing objects to the JFrame that are in fact the main reason for your problems. Instead, use just one Resizer class, and use it as a single MouseAdapter added to a single Resizing object. Then in this single class, allow **both** rectangles to be changed.

Please post comments if you have any questions.

---

You ask:

> Thank you, but how can I allow both rectangles to be changed ? In class Resizer, there is only one component (r) ?

There is only one component, but it holds ***two*** rectangles, and it knows the difference between the two rectangles since it has two rectangle variables.

---

**Edit 2**
Consider:

- Editing your original question and adding your new code to the bottom, deleting your redundant new question.
- Creating a non-GUI object, say called MyRectangle, that holds a Rectangle object.
- This new class can have methods that allow your to pass in a Point or an x and y positions, and return information to let the calling code know if the mouse is over the top or bottom edge (your code already does this, so this should be no problem for you).
- This new class will have mutator (setter) methods that allow outside classes set its rectangle y position and height.
- The new class will have a fill method that accepts a Graphics2D parameter and uses it to fill the Rectangle that it holds.
- Then give your Resizer class a `List<MyRectangle>`, actually an ArrayList of them, say called myRectangleList, and you can add two MyRectangle objects to it
- Then give Resizer a getMyRectangleList method that returns the list.
- Then in your MouseAdapter, iterate through the List to see if the mouse is over an edge
- etc...

e.g.,

```
class MyRectangle {
   private Rectangle rect;
   private String name;

   public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name) {
      rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void fill(Graphics2D g2) {
      g2.fill(rect);
   }

   public int getOutcode(Point p) {
      // return ... do what you need to figure tihs out
   }

   public boolean isOverRect(Point p) {
      // return ... do what you need to figure tihs out
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name + " " + rect.toString();
   }
}
```

And then something like:

```
public class Resizing2 extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private List<MyRectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();

   public Resizing2() {
      rectangleList.add(new MyRectangle(100, 100, 150, 150, "Rect 1"));
      rectangleList.add(new MyRectangle(300, 100, 150, 150, "Rect 2"));
   }

   public List<MyRectangle> getRectangleList() {
      return rectangleList;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
      for (MyRectangle rect : rectangleList) {
         rect.fill(g2);
      }
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   // ..... etc...
```

Comment: Please post comments if you have any questions., yes I'm have one - happy new year 2014, all the best ...

Comment: @mKorbel: thank you, and the same to you and your family -- a very happy, healthy and bountiful year to you!

Comment: Thank you, but how can I allow both rectangles to be changed ? In class Resizer, there is only one component (r) ?

Comment: I am a beginner in java programming, and I do not see at all how to do this.

Comment: @user3153920: If you know how to do the code you've already done, if this is all your code and with now "borrowed" code, you should know pretty much how to follow my suggestions. Please be specific with your questions. What exactly don't you understand? The better your questions the better we can help you. Also, please see edit to my answer.

Comment: Ok, see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951625/resize-2-rectangles-independently-in-java

Comment: In my code, the line "Rectangle r = component.rect;" allow resizing of the rectangle named rect, but for rect2 ?

Comment: @user3153920: please don't duplicate your question. Instead improve this one. This behavior can get you banned from this site since your duplication unnecessarily divides the problem and is not fair to the volunteers of this site. If it's a new question and your original question here has been answered, then mark it solved by accepting an answer and ask new information in the new question, but don't leave both hanging.

Comment: An idea for adapting "Rectangle r = component.rect;" to the list of rectangles ?

Comment: @user3153920: yep, you should do that.

Comment: Sorry ? It's your reply ?

Comment: I dont't know how doing that.

Comment: Someone can help me or it's desperate ?